# Automatic email notifications based on date in django

Tags: django, email, django-admin, notifications

I have to implement a way to send automatic notification emails based on a model DateFields. I'll put an example.

I have a DateField with 2010-07-23 stored in it and I want django to send an email to a designated user when the current date reaches a week before (send it in 2010-07-16). Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to set up an external job, probably triggered via cron, that checks the date and sends the email as necessary.

Comment: There's no way to trigger it through django? I can figure how to do it using django signals, but it's not efficient, if you don't do anything for a time, django will not check the dates...

Comment: Yes, use the cron job to call a Django script. I prefer to do these as custom manage.py commands: see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: It is not neccessay that cron call a django script.Simply check the time and send the email